# How to pass a array value as color in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, property-binding

I'm new in Angular and in stackoverflow. I need to know if can I pass the value of an array in the element bidding in Angular 4.

Basically I want change the color of the #jediSign if the student are or not a jedi!

This is the template:

```
<div *ngIf="student">
  Student: <a href="#" (click)="clicked()">{{student?.name}}</a>
  <br/>
  <div *ngIf="student?.isJedi">
  Jedi Temple: {{student?.temple}} <br/>
  </div>
  <div #jediSign class="jediSign"></div>
  <button (click)="jediSign.style.background='lightgreen'">Is Jedi?
  </button>
 </div>
```

And this is the component:

```
export class AppComponent {

 students: Student[] = [
  {
   name: 'Luke', 
   isJedi: true, 
   temple: 'Coruscant', 
   color: 'lightgreen'
   },
  {
   name: 'Leia', 
   isJedi: false, 
   color: 'red'
   },
  {
   name: 'Han Solo', 
   isJedi: false, 
   color: 'red'
  }
 ]
}
```

How can I change the color from 'lightgreen' to students.color?

I put this code on github for pull requests.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried the ngStyle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just should use `style.background` input:

```
<div *ngIf="student">
  Student: <a href="#" (click)="clicked()">{{student?.name}}</a>
  <br/>
  <div *ngIf="student?.isJedi">
  Jedi Temple: {{student?.temple}} <br/>
  </div>
  <div #jediSign class="jediSign" [style.background]="isJediBackgroundColor(student)" ></div>
  <button (click)="student.isJedi = !student.isJedi">Is Jedi?
  </button>
 </div>
```

function to get `isJedi` background color:

```
isJediBackgroundColor(student) {
  return student.isJedi ? student.color : '';
}
```

By the way `click` should toggle isJedi? :

```
(click)="student.isJedi = !student.isJedi"
```

Comment: Great! This solved my question. But the first result `<div>` already show the background color from the `student.color`. How can I show an default color and just change to `student.color` by clicking? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just by seting the color with ngStyle:

```
<div ... [ngStyle]="{'background-color': student.isJedi ?
 student.color : 'lightgrey'}"..>
```

and

```
  <button (click)="student.isJedi = !student.isJedi">...
```

Comment: It works. I've tried some like this, but using [style.backgroundColor]="student.color". This change the color of DIV but I need this change should come by clicking.